# Update from regexp matches in same table without using subquery

Tags: sql, arrays, regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to fill two columns from the results of a regular expression matching on a column of the same table.

Extracting the matches in an array is easy enough:

```
select regexp_matches(description, '(?i)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$') matches from room;
```

(note that only some of the rows match, not all of them)

But in order to do the update I didn't find anything simpler than

**1)** repeating the regex which would be ridiculous:

```
update room r set
    link=(regexp_matches(description, '(?i)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$'))[1],
    description=(regexp_matches(description, '(?i)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$'))[2]
where description ~ '(?i)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$';
```

**2)** a query with a subquery and an id join, which looks over complicated and probably not the most efficient:

```
update room r set link=matches[1], description=matches[2] from (
    select id, regexp_matches(description, '(?i)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$') matches from room
) s where matches is not null and r.id=s.id;
```

What's the proper solution here ? I suspect one of the magical array functions of postgresql would do the trick, or another regexp related function, or maybe something even simpler.

Comment: I think CTE with regex would be the most suitable?.. which would be the join as your second variant, but better looking probably

Comment: From 9.5, you could use the `SET ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )` syntax. Below that the best you can do is your 2nd solution (either with a CTE, or in its current form).

Comment: I would upvote a good answer even if it doesn't apply to 9.3. After all I'll have to update at some point...

Answer (score 2):

From 9.5, you can use the [following syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

```
with p(pattern) as (
  select '(?in)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$'
)
update room
set    (link, description) = (select m[1], m[2]
                              from   regexp_matches(description, pattern) m)
from   p
where  description ~ pattern;
```

This way `regexp_matches()` executed only once, but this will execute your regex twice. If you want to avoid that you'll need to use a join anyway. [Or, you could do](http://rextester.com/KRDIZJ4278):

```
update room
set    (link, description) = (
  select coalesce(m[1], l), coalesce(m[2], d)
  from   (select link l, description d) s,
         regexp_matches(d, '(?in)^(https?://\S{4,220}\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s(.*)$') m
);
```

But this will "touch" every row no matter what. It will just don't modify the values of `link` and `description` when there is no match.

Comment: Interesting but there's still a repetition of the regex execution, here. Can you solve that ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret repeating parameters usually don't matter when you use prepared statements. But if you want to pull out them too, you can use a CTE for that.

Comment: It's not about the parameter, it's about the regex execution (and I don't use prepared statements for this case). In any case this kind of destructuring is interesting.

Comment: @DenysSéguret the `LATERAL` solution should work in your case then.

Comment: It doesn't work for now: "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "room""

Comment: @DenysSéguret yeah it seems `UPDATE` protects its syntax in every way possible. You'll either need to use a join, or execute the regex twice.

Comment: @DenysSéguret ... or (technically) `UPDATE` every row (with a no-op `UPDATE`, when there is no match).